# Open a .ppt and .Key files in browser through .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I want to open the `.ppt` files in browser instead of download on click of a link, as for pdf it is working just by adding the file name in `.htaccess` so what is the rule to be written to open the `.ppt` file as well as `.key` file in browser instead of downloading that file.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can't really let the server decide, what shall be done with a file on the client side. It's more a property of the browser.